# how to pass a class and call a class's function javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, express, es6-class

I have this JS class

Agent.js

```
class Agent {
  constructor(agentId) {
    this.agentId = agentId
  }
  getProducts() {
    return arrayOfProducts[]
  }
}
```

In my login process, I create a new agent:

login.js

```
function login() {
  //tl;dr
  var agent = new Agent('123')
  req.user = agent
}
```

Here, I pass the agent to another function

index.js

```
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res, next) => {
      getUserData.dashboard(req.user, res, next)
    }, (req, res, next) => { //res.render...    });
```

I don't want to pass around the products from every view so at dashboard I try to get the agent data instead of login.

getUserData.js

```
var dashboard = (agent, res, next) => {
    console.log(typeof agent) // returns 'object'
    //get products
    var products = agent.getProducts();
next()
}

module.exports = {
dashboard : dashboard 
}
```

I get an error saying:

> getProducts() isn't a function.

How do I pass an agent and get its methods?

Comment: Try `console.log(agent.constructor.name)` and see what comes up.

Comment: Just to calrify, are you trying to call agent from the back end? or the front and after it's been serialized as JSON?

Comment: Have you done `console.log(agent)` and seen what properties this 'object' has? Additionally, confirm that `req.user` isn't simply `null`, as `typeof null === "object"` in JS.

Comment: where are you calling login(). are you sure any other middleware didn't overwrite `req.user`? console.log(agent) to be sure.

Comment: @EddieDelRio it comes up as object. Yes all of this is backend nodejs nothing in the post is client side

Comment: @TylerRoper yes i have and it shows me the actual properties but not the methods.

Comment: @douxsey when i log out agent I get {agentId:'123'}

Comment: @Meisterunner I feel like you're missing tags here. Is this node? express? You've only tagged vanilla JS but I can't help but feel there's more at play.

Comment: @TylerRoper yes, it's express 4.16.0 on  node v10.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using this on the front end you can pass each function as middlware until you're ready to structure you're response. I'd perform validation on each step to ensure the request body has everything needed to perform the operation. I'm not sure why you're calling what looks like another middleware function inside the actual endpoint definition. You can just chain the functions :D

```js
class Agent {
  constructor(agentId) {
    this.agentId = agentId
  }
  getProducts() {
    return arrayOfProducts[]
  }
}

function login(req, res. next) 
{
  //tl;dr
  //Just guessing what the query looks like
  let {_id} = req;
  AgentSchema.findById(_id)
  .then(agent => {
  
    var agent = new Agent(agent._id);
    req.agent = agent;
    next();
  })
  .catch(err => err.status(404).json('Not Found'));
}

function dashboard (req, res, next) => {
    let { agent } = req;
    if(!agent) next(createError(400, 'Agent Not Found on Request Body'));
    //get products
    var products = agent.getProducts();
    //Do some stuff *(Maybe send a response)?
};

//Pass login as middleware
router.get('/dashboard', login, dashboard)
```

Be advised though, if you're trying to use the method on the front end, JSON does not preserve methods, you'd have to redefine the class on the front and and construct an instance from the response body

Comment: Wont this create a new agent every time i pass it along? also the login function queries the database. I didn't put that in the code because i'm looking for an answer on how to pass a instance of a class along. so that i can call it's function when I need that function.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "Creating a new Agent every time I pass it along". The agent will be created when it hits the login middleware, after that, every function following will have access to the agent in the request body.

Comment: Everytime this endpoint is fired, an agent will be created, but if that agent is not saved any where, then the garbage collection will remove it.
If you only want one instance of agent, you'd have to use a Singleton design pattern

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by every time was:
 when I login I query the DB, from that I set the agentId to the new agent. I then pass that agent along through multiple routes (not just the one shown) if i use the login function on that route wont that create a different agent then the one I started with?

Comment: Yes that is what will hapen, but not multiple routes, multiple processes within the same route. Once that process is complete, the instance of Agent will be deleted from memory unless you want to persist it asomewhere

Comment: You can try running that tidy bit if you want and console logging products. be sure to call next or send a response, otherwise it'll timeout

Comment: so we actually have a very similar answer already but what your saying is I have to create a new instance every time I want to use it's methods. what im really asking is, is it possible to pass that instance around instead of creating a new one everytime i need to use a method. This class will have many different methods because there is a ton of data needed and I dont want to pass it around through every route.

Comment: There's a few options you can do than, look into a concept known as singletons. Where every time you refer to the same instance, the second option is static methods. If the functions do not rely data unique to the instance, you can use static methods that just refer to the constructor and not instances